# Less css: variables definition

Tags: css, less

I have to projects, basing on the same HTML and different CSS. I want to bring together the CSS definitions of those two projects in one Less file, with variables to define the differences.

Project 1:

```
.userbar {
    background: #fff;
}
```

Project 2:

```
.userbar {
    background:url(../images/bg-userbar.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

The merged Less Code should be:

```
userbar {background: @bg_userbar}
```

Then I can define the color for project 1 like this:

```
@bg_userbar: #fff;
```

But for project 2, is this valid less code?

```
@bg_userbar: background:url(../images/bg-userbar.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;
```

Many thanks for your help!
Sascha.

Comment: Wasn't aware of Less. Seems interesting. Like the sort of Variables, so-to-speak, that you can accomplish with Less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just spent some time again with this issue.

```
@bg_userbar: url(../images/bg-userbar.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;
.userbar {
    background:@bg_userbar;
}
```

is valid less code and compiles to

```
.userbar {
  background: url(../images/bg-userbar.png) no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

But thanks for the hint with escaping; although it's not necessary.

Answer (score 4):

the first variable definition is of course valid, for the second one you just need to escape it:

```
@bg_userbar: #fff;
@bg_userbar: ~"url(../images/bg-userbar.png) no-repeat 100% 100%";

.userbar {background: @bg_userbar}
```